# What are the steps and thought process behind translating Exclusive Propositions into Standard Categorical Form?

Tags: logic

<sub>Source: p 256, *A Concise Introduction to Logic* (12 Ed, 2014) by Patrick Hurley</sub>

> Many propositions that involve the words “only,” “none but,” “none except,” and
>   “no . . . except” are exclusive propositions. Efforts to translate them into categorical
>   propositions often lead to confusing the subject term with the predicate term. To avoid
>   such confusion keep in mind that language following “only,” “none but,” “none except,”
>   and “no . . . except” goes in the predicate term of the categorical proposition. For example,
>   the statement
>
> 1. “Only executives can use the silver elevator”    is translated
>      [✓] 2. “All people who can use the silver elevator are executives.” [✓]
>
> If it were translated
>   [✘] 3. “All executives are people who can use the silver elevator,”
>   the translation would be incorrect. [✘]

I accept that 2 is the correct, and 3 is the incorrect, translation of 1; but I wish to dig deeper: What are the steps and thought processes behind translating 3 (the generalisation of 1) into 4 (the generalisation of 2)? Can a Venn Diagram depict why only 4 is correct, and 5 is incorrect?

> 3. Only A are B.       ✓ 4. All B are A. ✓      ✘ 5. All A are B. ✘

<sub>I already read the textbook's caution on the ambiguity of 'only', about which I ask not:</sub>

> <sub>Also note that many English statements containing “only” are ambiguous because
>   “only” can be interpreted as modifying alternate words in the statement. [...]</sub>

Comment: Only A are B ==  No non-A is B ==  Every B is not a non-A == All B are A

Answer (score 1):

I'll simplify a little bit the example :

> Only Greeks are Boethians.

This is translated into logical form as :

> All Boethians are Greek,

i.e. according to the schema : "All **B** are **A**".

This can be visualized as a Venn diagram where the set of **B**s is (fully) included into the set of **A**s; being so, there is no **B** that is not "an **A**", i.e. "Only **A** are **B**".

"All **A** are **B**", instead, will be visualized with the set of **A**s (fully) included into the set of **B**s; this is compatible with the fact that we can have some **B** "outside" the set of **A**s, i.e. some *Beothian*, call it *Bob*, that is not **A**, i.e. it is not a *Greek*.

In this case it is not true that "Only **A** are **B**", because *Bob* is a *Beothians* which is not an **A**, i.e. not a *Greek*.